# @Ajax.ActionLink OnComplete pass this

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

Why this code don't working? I want to pass a reference to `<a href ='' .. </ a>` and hide it

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("titie", "List", new { id = Model.id },
   new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "someDiv", HttpMethod = "GET", OnComplete = "change(this)")},null)

  <script type="text/javascript">  
   function change(link) {
    $(link).hide();
   }
  </script>
```

Comment: Are you trying to hide the link or trying to hide the href attributes value?

Comment: I trying to hide a link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add in **jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js** :
 `options.context = element;` (~ 100 line)

And you can use this in asp.net mvc html helpers

Answer (score 1):

Do it this way:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("titie", "List", new { id = Model.id },
  new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "someDiv", HttpMethod = "GET", OnComplete = "change")},
new { id="link" })
```

JS:

```
function change(){
    $('#link').hide();
}
```

Your code does not work because `this` in your case references ajax request object, not anchor element

Answer (score 0):

You need to directly hide the link with the HTML Id. You can give the actionlink an Id with this overload.

```
Ajax.ActionLink( string linkText,
             string action,
             object routeValues,
             AjaxOptions ajaxOptions,
             object htmlAttributes )

@Ajax.ActionLink("titie", "List", new { id = Model.id }, 
new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "someDiv", HttpMethod = "GET",
OnComplete = "change(this)")}, new {id = "linkToBeHidden"}})
```

Now you can hide the link by Id

```
<script type="text/javascript">  

     $( "#linkToBeHidden" ).on( "click", function() {
               $('#linkToBeHidden').hide();
     });

</script>
```